# How to use soundex function in Jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Could someone please guide me on how to use soundex in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). I tried looking into jOOQ documentation but it is not clear. Please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is about the SQL Server [`SOUNDEX()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) function? There's currently no native support for this function in jOOQ 3.2, although support is on the roadmap with [#2969](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2969). As always with unsupported stuff in jOOQ, you can resort to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/), creating a custom Field like this:

```
Field<String> fn = DSL.field("SOUNDEX({0})", String.class, argument);
```

See the [`DSL.field()` Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.2.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.jooq.QueryPart...%29) for details.